# Where can I ask questions about Siebel configuration?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, specific-question

I want to ask few questions about Siebel configuration, but I do not know where to ask'em. I followed [startups.com](http://startups.com/) and tried to post my questions there, but as a new-user I can't create new tags (siebel) there. I am not getting any responses either.

Comment: What's the question about?

Comment: She asked about getting good documentation for Siebel. See here http://startups.com/questions/10024/siebel-where-i-can-find-siebel-tutorial-or-guide-to-start-from-basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that, like with questions about Facebook and WolframAlpha, contact the Siebel support, which would be [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/siebel/support.html).

There seems to be no stackexchange site suitable. Maybe startups.com and [Answers.OnStartUps.Com](http://answers.onstartups.com/) are the best choice there.

There will be no look on SO, SF or Meta. Even on SU your question will most probably be closed (as it is plain product support).

Comment: ohk .. I will see ..

Comment: They are down-voting it .. :(

Comment: Moreover being a new user I can't create any new tags in OnStartUps.com

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do, if your trying to integrate Siebel in your exisiting IT infrastructure, then Serverfault should be able to help, I've had some experience with Siebel. If you need help with customising Siebel, such as writing config files, you might get some help on SF, but it'll be pretty limited.

Comment: ya .. I agree .. actually .. the problem is .. there are only few experts in siebel and they don't want to (to be positive .. they can't) share the knowledge ..

Comment: thanx for the response :)